# physical meaning of pressure derivatives

Tags: pressure, ideal-gas

Is there any physical meaning of the first and second derivatives of pressure with respect to time? If this helps, I am considering ideal gases.

Comment: Derivative of pressure with respect to what?

Comment: With respect to time

Comment: ...like in a sound wave?

Comment: @mikuszefski yes , for example. or pressure waves in a gas.

Comment: Well, I guess a sound wave is sort of a pressure wave, which then would have time and space derivatives. As stated in the comment to Surgical Commander, it is sometimes good to see pressure as an energy density. So a pressure gradient is an energy density gradient and corresponds to a non equilibrium situation. In the Bernoulli tube case it is a pure space derivative in a dynamic equilibrium. In the sound wave case it has space and time derivatives and the energy gradient results in energy transport.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is a physical meaning to the derivatives of pressure. Pressure is defined as a force/area, and derivatives of pressure physically correspond to the rate of change of this quantity. If the derivatives are in time, the derivatives tell you how fast the pressure is changing in time, just like it would for any function. If the derivatives are in space, then this tells you how rapidly the pressure is varying from one location to another.

Pressure gradients are a common occurrence in physics and the natural sciences: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_gradient.

Comment: In gases it is sometimes more convenient not to think in terms of force/area; in this special case with a gradient in pressure even more. Note that pressure can also be interpreted as energy density as in [Bernoulli's Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle). And of course a Bernoulli style flow experiment with tubes of varying radius is a simple way to get those gradients.

Comment: With displacement derivatives lead to unique names - velocity, acceleration, jerk. Any similar naming for derivatives of pressure? Or just 'pressure gradient'? Perhaps pressure-velocity, pressure-accleration, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In fluid mechanics the gradient of the pressure is the force per unit volume on an infinitesimal fluid element.

$$d\vec{F} = - \vec{\nabla} p d\tau $$